# jmeter not recording second page after login

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I am trying to load test a web application for XYZ form
However when I m recording the action performed on the form , only login and login operations are captured , rest other actions performed by me are not been captured..
Below is the screenshot of the properly captured HTML response for the Login Page i.e. my first step: 
[image]
After successful login dashboard page gets opened , but its corresponding Response HTML is blank
Below is screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Please provide some more information, post some code you have tried...

Comment: proper response is not always HTML, it can be many other things (whatever server returns). Why do you think response data is incorrect? What do you see if you invoke Network tab in Developer tools in the browser?

Comment: When OP is trying to reuse the same script with multiple users login id (used CSV data set config and Regular expression extractor).
then only login operations are captured , rest other actions are not captured for multiple users.